# php + Xampp: Firefox slow for no reason

Tags: php, firefox, xampp

i'm using the latest version of firefox (50.1.0) for coding php using xampp.
anything is blazing fast, eg. loading a simple web in 20ms, but from time to time it's REALLY slow .. it seems to be a bug in firefox as when i'm reloading my page several times it's mostly fast but a few time slow - see firebug's network screenshot below:
[image]

as you can see, the web requires 27ms only but the total is 2,47 seconds.

any idea what is causing this and how it can be fixed?
thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug in firefox and not caused by the server?

Comment: as i said, when reloading the same page several times, app. each 3rd time it's really slow .. there's no db access, only plain html.

Comment: its due to firebug add-on.

Answer (score 0):

seems like i found the reason:

Power Plan

Change Windows Power Plan (also called Power Options, in Control Panel) from the default of “Balanced” (or “Power Saver”) to “High Performance”. “Balanced” restricts CPU Scaling. This can increase performance 50%.